# combine fields and values in python for dictionary

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I'm probably overlooking something, but I've looked everywhere for a way to do this. I am trying to join fields and values together that come out separated for SQL to something i can use with MongoDB.

So for example (input):

```
fields = ['first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address', 'phone-number']
values = ['John', 'Doe', 'john.doe@johndoe.com', '1-800-123-4567']
```

Output:

```
{
    'first-name':'John',
    'last-name':'Doe',
    'email':'john.doe@johndoe.com',
    'phone-number':'1-800-123-4567'
}
```

I need it like this so i can just do a simple (I know i don't need to do this):

```
def getFirstName(self, lastname):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client.test.contacts
    result db.find({ 'last-name':lastname })
    return result['first-name']

self.getFirstName("Doe")
```

My app supports MySQL and PostgreSQL so I can't really change how it spits fields and values without breaking those. Sorry if i made code errors, i typed this at the top of my head.

If you need more info, just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `zip` to wrap the two lists together and pass that to `dict()`

```
dict(zip(fields, values))
```

this assumes though that the two lists are always the same length

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dict comprehension and iterate through the lists like:

```
d = {fields[i] : values[i] for i in range(len(fields))}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Actually if I were you I'd use the other answer, it's generally more Pythonic than using a counter like I am. I had forgotten about zip() when I suggested mine.

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for the tip.